# opam report config file is missing

Tags: opam

I am on a Mac OS X 10.9.5

when I type:

opam list -a

I get:

## opam-version    1.2.0

## os              darwin

File /Users/edkeith/.opam/repo/default/config does not exist

I get the same thing when I type :

opam install batteries

if I type :

opam init --comp=4.02.1

I get :

OPAM has already been initialized.# opam-version    1.2.0

## os              darwin

File /Users/edkeith/.opam/repo/default/config does not exist

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the tree under ~/.opam and reinstalled. It is working fine now.